# python-opencv How i can convert file-object to numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, opencv

```
url = 'http://www.xxxx.1.jpg'
fobj = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
f = open('1.jpg','wb')
f.write(fobj)

img = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
```

**Can I have any better way?I don't want to save file everytime!**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cv2.imdecode()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imdecode) to directly read the image data. But it needs to be transformed into a `numpy.ndarray` first:

```
jpeg_array = bytearray(fobj)
img = cv2.imdecode(np.asarray(jpeg_array), cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
```